# WMVCore crashes when WMIsContentProtected methos was called

Tags: c++, media

My team is developing an application that is capable of recording videos and exporting the video into .wmv format file.
The export function is done via a method that utilizes windows API method derived from WMVCore.dll library.
However, on some PCs, this export function gets into crashes and according to the dump file taken from the crash, it appears that the last method called was `WMVCore.WMIsContentProtected` method. The call stack from the dump file is like below:

```
379fe8d8 65aa0cdb 299f94f0 00025800 379fe8f4
WMVCORE!WMIsContentProtected+0x4bc3 379fe970 6102e07e 1cae3f20
299f94f0 379fece8 WMVCORE!WMCreateWriterPushSink+0x1e278
```

It is really frustrating getting this crash without any more information out of the dump file. I also thought that the library might be corrupted on that specific PC, but there is no way to re-install the library as it comes with Windows Media Player. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

The code simply called `WMVCore.WMCreateWriterPushSink` which is followed by `WMVCore.WMIsContentProtected`. The OS version is Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit. The application is a web based application on IE, in which case when the crash happens, IE would also crash and stop. The version of the WMVCore.dll is 12.0.7601.17514 and the question here is whether anyone has experienced the same issue and if yes, what sort of things can be tried/done to prevent this crash from happening?

Comment: _"The call stack from the dump file is like below ..."_ And now? What was the code actually causing that error, what were the actual envrionment/OS versions, version of the media library? We're not able to remote debug that stuff for you, so what's the actual concern asking here?

Comment: The code simply called "WMVCore.WMCreateWriterPushSink" which is followed by "WMVCore.WMIsContentProtected". The OS version is Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit. The application is a web based application on IE, in which case when the crash happens, IE would also crash and stop. The version of the WMVCore.dll is 12.0.7601.17514 and the question here is whether anyone has experienced the same issue and if yes, what sort of things can be tried/done to prevent this crash from happening? Sorry for unclear question

Comment: _@TTKurama_ [Improve your question please!](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28420353/edit)